# how to insert value into DataGridView Cell?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have `DataGridView` (that hold any `DataBase`)

I want to insert any value into any Cell (and that this value will save on DataBase)

How to do it (in C#)

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 22):

You can access any DGV cell as follows :

```
dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value = value;
```

But usually it's better to use databinding : you bind the DGV to a data source (`DataTable`, collection...) through the `DataSource` property, and only work on the data source itself. The `DataGridView` will automatically reflect the changes, and changes made on the `DataGridView` will be reflected on the data source

Comment: On which even we can edit and add value and save it to database

Answer (score 19):

This is perfect code but it cannot add a new row:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value = value;
```

But this code can insert a new row:

```
var index = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
this.dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = "1";
this.dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value = "Baqar";
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the index are not fixed in the second example.

Answer (score 3):

For Some Reason I could Not add Numbers(in string Format) to the DataGridView
But This Worked For Me Hope it help someone!

```
//dataGridView1.Rows[RowCount].Cells[0].Value = FEString3;//This was not adding Stringed Numbers like "1","2","3"....
DataGridViewCell NewCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();//Create New Cell
NewCell.Value = FEString3;//Set Cell Value
DataGridViewRow NewRow = new DataGridViewRow();//Create New Row
NewRow.Cells.Add(NewCell);//Add Cell to Row
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(NewRow);//Add Row To Datagrid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int index= datagridview.rows.add();
datagridview.rows[index].cells[1].value=1;
datagridview.rows[index].cells[2].value="a";
datagridview.rows[index].cells[3].value="b";
```

hope this help! :)

Comment: Thank a lot! It's much easier this way!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function if you want to add the data into database, with a button. I hope it will help.

```
// dgvBill is name of DataGridView

string StrQuery;
try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectingString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
        {
            comm.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            for (int i = 0; i < dgvBill.Rows.Count; i++) 
            {
                StrQuery = @"INSERT INTO tblBillDetails (IdBill, productID, quantity, price,  total) VALUES ('" + IdBillVar+ "','" + dgvBill.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "', '" + dgvBill.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value + "', '" + dgvBill.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "', '" + dgvBill.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + "');";
                comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();         
             }
         }
     }
 }
 catch (Exception err)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(err.Message  , "Error !");
 }
```