# How to add a new column to datagridview after binding it with database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a `dataGridView` in my winForm (C#) application to display a list of Players.

I have successfully bound it with the database and its showing all columns i.e PlayerName, Age, Runs etc. correctly.

Now i want to add one more columns i.e 'CurrentScore' to this `dataGridView` at `run time` without adding to database.

Plz tell how to perform this tast.  Is it possible to add new column programmatically ??

```
    private  void playerList(int teamID)
    {


            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            string query = "SELECT PlayerName AS [Player Name] ,Age , Runs FROM Players WHERE Team_id= " + teamID;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(ds, "Players");
            dGridPlayers.DataSource = ds.Tables["Players"];

        }
```

this code is working perfectly  **but not able to add new temporary column 'CurrentScore`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just edit your query and add a dummy column:

```
string query = "SELECT player_name AS [Player Name] ,
skill As [Skill], '' AS [CurrentScore]
FROM Players WHERE Team_id= " + teamID;
```

Comment: thanks @gian.. its working fine...

Can you please tell me how to add values to this column (specially cell by cell)..

Comment: where will the values be coming from? is it entered manually on the form?

Comment: generating some random values and  display them to the new column cell (one by one)

Comment: you can this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397895/how-to-insert-value-into-datagridview-cell